# How to change Doxygen Configuration file

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to change the following to be 
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES

I change this directly from doxyfile however when I run the doxywizard it seems like reading another doxyfile that has the following variables sets to NO
 EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO

How can I know which configuration file that doxywizard is reading from?

Answer (score 1):

Just load the right configuration file and it should work or change it in doxywizard -> Expert -> Build -> check the EXTRACT_ALL and EXTRACT_PRIVATE boxes.